# Delete all achives from AWS S3 Glacier Vault instead of deleting one by one

Tags: amazon-glacier

I am looking for a way to delete multiple archives from AWS S3 Glacier.

I found ways to delete archives by id one by one, using AWSPowershell,awscli and Rest API.

Is there a way in which I can delete all archives in one execution by using any wildcard for the archives' id??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single API or AWS provided single click to do this task.
You can write a simple script or will find many examples (like https://gist.github.com/veuncent/ac21ae8131f24d3971a621fac0d95be5).

You have to - Generate inventory and send delete request for each archive ID.

You can call AWS APIs as well.
During development, you can make REST API calls to Glacier using postman:
https://medium.com/@nisarg.1611/how-to-call-aws-s3-glacier-rest-apis-from-postman-e3db527508d5

Please update if you have found any other way.